# Синтаксис Java в частности lambda

Tags: java

Если можно, исходя из выражения, подскажите, пожaлуйста, как его перевести в выражение на Java 7.

```
private static final Predicate<Object> removeDotPred = symbol -> !MULTI_ARGS_SIGNAL.equals(symbol);
```

Comment: посмотрите на [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda), может поможет...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Как уже было сказано `Predicate` в Java 7 нет. Если этот интерфейс хотите создать в Java 7 то он должен выглядеть как-то так

```
public interface Predicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}
```

и тогда можно заменить код на

```
private static final Predicate<Object> removeDotPred = new Predicate<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Object symbol) {
        return !MULTI_ARGS_SIGNAL.equals(symbol);
    }
};
```